# Vue allow components anywhere, not just in #app

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

Right now I'm setting my Vue instance with the following:

```
import ListClubsComponent from "./components/clubs/list-clubs.vue";
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        "list-clubs": ListClubsComponent
    }
});
```

This is working but only if a component is inside of `<div id="app">` but the odd thing is that only the Vue component will be rendered, if I have any HTML inside of the app div it will not be rendered.

I am using this on a Laravel with Blade project. My default template is as follows:

```
<body>

    @include('templates.header')

    <main id="app">
        <h1>This won't be rendered</h1>

        <!-- This will be rendered -->
        <list-clubs :player="{!! $player !!}"></list-clubs>
    </main>

    @include('templates.footer')
</body>
```

list-clubs.vue

```
<template>
    <h1>List Clubs Component</h1>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from "vue";
    import Component from "vue-class-component";
    import { Clubs } from "../../modules/clubs";

    export default class ListClubsComponent extends Vue {}
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to be working here: https://jsfiddle.net/hrtopk74/

Comment: I am not trying to render just HTML, I will post the component code above.

Comment: Looks like you're importing `Component` from `vue-class-component` but you're never using it. I've found that funny things happen when you extend vue without using the `@Component` decorator.

Comment: @CraigHarshbarger That seemed to fix it, thanks!

Comment: I went ahead and posted that as an answer since that was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are importing `Component` from `vue-class-component` but you're not using it when you extend `Vue` in your `ListClubsComponent`. Funny things happen when you extend vue without using the `@Component` decorator. Make sure you use it

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Vue from "vue";
    import Component from "vue-class-component";

    @Component
    export default class ListClubsComponent extends Vue {}
</script>
```